Why Sitecore renders url of media item as short id?
For some reason when Sitecore renders links to media items, they are rendered as
/-/media/fd0a64ae236c4d668053b2cb233aeacf.pdf

instead of rendering file path and name. Here is my mediaUrlBuilder config section:
<mediaUrlBuilder type="Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.MediaUrlBuilder, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <param type="Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.DefaultMediaUrlBuilderOptions, Sitecore.Kernel" desc="defaultOptions">
        <alwaysIncludeServerUrl ref="links/urlBuilder/alwaysIncludeServerUrl"/>
        <alwaysExcludeVirtualFolder ref="links/urlBuilder/alwaysExcludeVirtualFolder"/>
        <languageEmbedding ref="links/urlBuilder/languageEmbedding"/>
        <languageLocation ref="links/urlBuilder/languageLocation"/>
        <lowercaseUrls ref="links/urlBuilder/lowercaseUrls"/>
        <encodeNames ref="links/urlBuilder/encodeNames"/>
        <absolutePath>true</absolutePath>
        <includeExtension>true</includeExtension>
        <useDisplayName>true</useDisplayName>
    </param>
    <param desc="mediaLinkPrefix">$(1)</param>
</mediaUrlBuilder>


Apparently there must be some issues with Sitecore 10.4 and useDisplayName parameter of DefaultMediaUrlBuilderOptions.
Changing useDisplayName to false did the trick - now all the media urls are built as full item path.
Here is the patch file I used:
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" >
  <sitecore>
    <links>
      <mediaUrlBuilder>
        <param desc="defaultOptions">
          <useDisplayName><patch:delete /></useDisplayName>
          <useDisplayName>false</useDisplayName>
        </param>
      </mediaUrlBuilder>
    </links>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

